# Setting WhatsApp Cloud API Callback URL Programmatically

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm trying to configure the callback URL for the WhatsApp Cloud API programmatically but haven't been able to find the relevant endpoint in the documentation. Currently, I can only set it through the UI in the developer console. Can this configuration be achieved using API calls instead?

want to send a API request which include the callback URL and other parameters and it be configured for Webhooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#configure-webhooks-product says:

> Once your endpoint or sample app is ready, use your app's App Dashboard to add and configure the Webhooks product. You can also do this programmatically by using the [/{app-id}/subscriptions endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v19.0/app/subscriptions) for all Webhooks except Instagram.

Although I am not really sure what type of `object` you would need to subscribe to for WhatsApp webhooks - not sure if that goes via the `page` type?

Comment: Thanks for the link, was able to get the data unfortunately Webhooks for WhatsApp is not supported. WhatsApp webhooks must be configured using the App Dashboard.